# Recommended project structure for Flex builds

Tags: apache-flex, build-process, flexbuilder

I'm starting a new project using Flex3 for a reasonably intricate UI getting its data from a collection of RESTful web services. I wondering what experiences others have had in structuring a moderately complex Flex project. The issues I'm thinking about include:

- I want to use our FlexBuilder licenses for visual editing of layouts and debugging code on Eclipse
- automated build script so that we can use a CI server
- testing strategies, particularly automatable unit tests
- cross-platform Linux and Windows development environments (yes, I know the Linux version of FlexBuilder doesn't do visual editing, but everything else should ideally run cross-platform)
- dependency management for at least the Java code (are there library dependency managers for Flex?)

I've just burned a day trying and failing to get a maven2/flex/jetty build setup working smoothly (based on [Jeff Maury's tutorial](http://riadiscuss.jeffmaury.com/2008/09/maven-and-flex-builder-tutorial-part-i.html)). I'm not dead-against using Maven as we go forwards, but I'm sure there must be a less painful route. The main issue I had (other than maven documentation being patchy) is that maven's "single artifact per build" rule means that you have to jump through a lot of hoops with a complex build, and I'm not enough of a maven initiate not to trip over the hoops and fall on my face!

Would Ant and Ivy be a better option than maven2? What other choices are there?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Flex development but I know CI so I'll comment on that aspect.

I work on [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/), so that's what I use (when not being paid to setup something else). And there are blog entries that describe setting up Flex projects under CC for both [Windows](http://www.eyefodder.com/blog/2006/05/continuous_integration_with_fl_5.shtml) and [Linux](http://weblogs.macromedia.com/pmartin/archives/2007/01/continous_integ.html). CC has been around for a long time so there is a large community of users and lots of [3rd party tools](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/3rdPartyCCStuff) that work with it.

But other people are likely to recommend [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) and it would be hard to argue against them. Hudson is very easy to get up and running and has a nice web based UI. This project is very active, has lots of fans and lots of buzz and has matured very rapidly. I don't have anything bad to say about it. This blog entry describes [running acceptance tests under Hudson](http://www.blackpepper.co.uk/black-pepper-blog/Adding-Selenium-Flex-tests-to-a-Hudson-job.html).

I don't know enough about Maven to offer advice there but I'm working with Ivy at a client right now and I really like it. We've got a combination of Java and C++ code and we're able to get Ivy to do what we need.

Answer (score 1):

Well we are using maven. With some help of a lot of different web sties I have an enterprise application being built using maven.

This article via adobe has really help a lot.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/fullstack_pt1.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/fullstack_pt2.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/fullstack_pt3.html

You really need a common configuration project that will be shared between both flex and java, and possibly your c++ code. This article explains how to set that all up.

Down side, if you are not knowledgeable with maven there is a slight learning curve.